# Dot size in pairs plot

Tags: r

I managed to make a plot with the r function "pairs" (the value of the Kendall tau's in the lower panel and pairs-plots in upper panel). Still i have one problem. How do I change the size of the dots in my upper panel? This is my code.

```
panel.Kendall <- function(x,y,digits=2, prefix="", cex.cor)
{
usr <- par("usr"); on.exit(par(usr))
par(usr = c(0, 1, 0, 1))
r <- Kendall(x, y)$tau
txt <- format(c(r, 0.123456789), digits=digits)[1]
txt <- paste(prefix, txt, sep="")
if(missing(cex.cor)) cex <- 0.8/strwidth(txt)
text(0.5, 0.5, txt, cex = cex * 0.5)
}
png("Kendall1.jpg",width=600,height=600,res=100)
pairs(all[c(2,6,8,9,10,11,14,15)],lower.panel=panel.Kendall)
dev.off()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define own function also for the `upper.panel=` (for example, `panel.points`) where you set points size with `cex=`

```
panel.points<-function(x,y)
{
  points(x,y,cex=3)
}

pairs(iris[,1:4],lower.panel=panel.Kendall,upper.panel=panel.points)
```